# How to prove a continuously differentable complex-valued functions on a domain $D$ is analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f =u+iv$ and the Jacobian matrix of $f$ does not vanish at any point of $D$.$f$ maps orthogonal curves to orthogonal curves then $f$
or conjugation of $f$ is analytic.

Comment: $f$ or $\overline{f}$ are conformal (depending on whether $\det(Jf)>0$ or $\det(Jf)<0$). Since conformal maps are holomorphic, and holomorphic functions are analytic, the claim is proved.

Comment: But we only know that the Jacobian matrix of f does not vanish .

Comment: maps orthogonal curves to orthogonal curves

Comment: Is this condition useless？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comment already said the idea is that either $f$ or $\bar f$ is conformal. But this requires a bit of thought to prove.

**1. The Jacobian is either a rotation-dilation or a rotation-dilation plus a reflection**

Take any two (differentiable) curves $\gamma,\eta$ orthogonally intersecting at a given point $\gamma(t_0)=\eta(t_0)=:z_0\in D$. This means that $\langle\partial_t\gamma(t_0),\partial_t\eta(t_0)\rangle=0$. Here, $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the Euclidean inner product.

By assumption, $f(\gamma)$ and $f(\eta)$ also intersect orthogonally at $f(z_0)$, which means that $\langle\partial_t f(\gamma(t_0)),\partial_t f(\eta(t_0))\rangle=0$. You can use the chain rule to show that $\mathrm D f(z_0)$ preserves orthogonal relationships. It is known that only rotations, dilations, reflections and their compositions do this. Among these, the linear transformations which don't incorporate reflections have positive determinant, whilethose that do have negative determinant. With the exception of the zero transformation, which has determinant 0, but the Jacobian is specified to never be the zero transformation.

**2. At any given point, either $f$ or $\bar f$ is complex differentiable**

The Cauchy-Riemann equations show us that $f$ is complex differentiable if its Jacobian is a rotation-dilation (no reflection). Just notice that the components of the Jacobian are the partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$, and that rotation-dilation matrices are such that the CR-equations are forced to be fulfilled. So $f$ is complex differentiable.

If, however, the Jacobian is a rotation-dilation with reflection, then the Jacobian of $\bar f$ is a rotation dilation without reflection. You can show this using the chain rule, where the Jacobian of complex conjugation is

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}.$$

In this case, $\bar f$ is complex differentiable.

**3. If at some point $f$ is complex differentiable and $\bar f$ is not, then this is the case on the entire domain. The reverse is also true.**

Consider the determinant of the Jacobian of $f$. Since the Jacobian is assumed to be continuous, and the determinant is continuous anyway, the function $\det\mathrm Df:D\to\mathbb R\backslash\{0\}$ is continuous. Continuous functions preserve connectedness. As $D$ is a domain, it is connected, so the image of this function is connected as well. Since $0$ is not in the image (rotation-dilations and reflections are invertible), the image is either entirely negative, or entirely positive. Since the sign of the determinant tells us wether we have a reflection or not, this means that we either have a reflection everywhere, or nowhere. So either $f$ is complex differentiable on all of $D$ (making it holomorphic), or $\bar f$ is.